# How do I use missiles?

Tags: lost-ruins

I recently noticed I had 4 missiles in my inventory that I can't equip. I'm not able to equip the missiles directly, similar to the arrows. How do I use the missiles? Is there a weapon somewhere I need to fire them?

[image: 4 missiles in inventory]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Missile Launcher is locked behind the Castle Upper Sanctum door on the 3rd floor of the castle.

[image: Map location of the Missile Launcher]

The Castle Upper Sanctum Key is found during the quest "Lusty's Request". Head to the castle and talk to the maid to the right of the Upper Sanctum door to accept the quest, then head one room to the right and fight the robot maid.

[image: robot maid fight]

Once defeated she will drop the Castle Upper Sanctum Key. Pick it up, head back to the right, and use the key to open the door and pickup the missile launcher.

[image: Missile launcher in the castle upper sanctum]

Sources:

- [Lost Ruins Map & Collection Guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2549805822) by Alisterchadwick
- [Lost Ruins 100% Full Game (2 Endings) Walkthrough Gameplay](https://youtu.be/HJAv0plda8o?t=13281) by MoonGirl Gaming
- Myself (verified the instructions)